# can not write more than 1000 rows using phpexcel

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpexcel

I am trying to populate excel with some data fetched from mysql DB. The problem i am facinng is that it is not populating more than 1000 rows when data contains around 1392 entries.
The code i am using here to write through PHPExcel is:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
     $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I have tried increasing memory limit and max_execution_time in php.ini but it did not result in any good news. Can anyone suggest the best way to rectify?

Comment: Start by reading about cell caching in PHPExcel: and look at using https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel for Laravel and PHPExcel, it makes things a lot easier

Comment: @MarkBaker : Thanks Mark. I am going to try this.

Comment: Hi, I tried using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel but getting below error:  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - maatwebsite/excel v1.1.5 requires phpoffice/phpexcel ~1.8.0 -> no matching package found.
    - maatwebsite/excel v1.1.4 requires phpoffice/phpexcel ~1.8.0 -> no matching package found.

Comment: got the following information as well:Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems." but could not get any help.

Comment: @MarkBaker : Hi Mark , Can u please suggest here?